# Duplicate column name error when creating a table from a select

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, ddl

I have a join on 3 tables with a large number of fields. Post join keep getting an error due to duplicate column names. Using alias has not solved the problem for me.

Is there a way of dropping the duplicate column before joining. I can't afford to select the required columns.

```
create temp table ashresults 
as 
select * 
from gp p 
  inner join gv v on p.fd1 = v.fd1 
  inner join gdc duc on p.id = duc.id 
where cast(v.rt as int) >= 1000 
and cast(v.cn as date ) >= '2016-07-01'
```

This statement is giving an error

Comment: `fd1` and `id` appear in more than one table, but `select *` selects them all. You have to explicitly list all columns and select only one of them or rename them using an alias.

Answer (score 1):

fd1 column exist in multiple table so you have to select table.column_name other wise it will be thrown error

```
  select p.*,duc.*,gv.* 
    from gp p 
      inner join gv v on p.fd1 = v.fd1 
      inner join gdc duc on p.id = duc.id 
    where cast(v.rt as int) >= 1000 
    and cast(v.cn as date ) >= '2016-07-01'
```

Comment: Is there a way to drop the columns that are duplicated instead of selecting 100 fields manually ?

Comment: from where you want to delete? from selection or from table?

Comment: from the result of selection not from the table

Comment: @AdurthiAshwinSwarup you to write explicitly  tablename.columnname in selection and you can rename it by using alias

Answer (score 1):

If the only duplicated columns are the ones used for the `join` conditions *and* `id` is only in `p` and `duc`, then you can use `using`:

```
select * 
from gp p join
     gv v 
     using (fd1) join
     gdc duc 
     using (id)
where cast(v.rt as int) >= 1000 and
      cast(v.cn as date ) >= '2016-07-01';
```

Comment: this answer is awesome!!!! I am new to Redshift and coming from R find this using the most convenient